# Capturar salida de un script R

Tags: python, r

Tengo un script en R al que llamo desde Python y quiero capturar la salida que de. Puedo escribir en el CMD, así como en un TXT, pero querría capturar la salida en el script de Python para poder trabajar con ella.

En el script de Python he probado con:

```
logging.debug(os.popen('Rscript testScript.r'))
```

Pero no da resultado. También he probado con:

```
salida = cmd('Rscript testScript.r')
print(salida)
```

Pero me devuelve **`None`** como salida.

En R he probado con: `returnValue(TRUE)` pero escribe en el CMD, y la salida sigue siendo **`None`**.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el script de R devuelva un valor que pueda filtrar para ver el resultado???

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución:

En R podemos poner dentro de un **`Try/catch`** la opción

```
 error=function(cond)
```

Esto nos refleja una salida que en Python podemos recoger como:

```
 print(stderr)
 print(stdout)
```

Dónde **`stderr`** es el error de salida y **`stdout`** es la salida estandar.

Espero que si alguien tiene un problema similar le ayude.